# Unable to Delete Wordpress Admin account from wp_users or Users Page on Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel, wordpress-admin

I am in a fix here.
I am trying to delete one of the admin accounts I created for a temporary use

It just doesn't get deleted at all

I have tried deleting through the following methods:

1. Main users page in the dashboard
2. wp_users page in Cpanel (Phpmyadmin)
3. Tried to delete all fake users in metadata in Cpanel (Phpmyadmin)

After deleting through methods, the page displays deleted successfully but the deleted admin account reappears after either logout/login or refreshing the page.

I have also tried changing the role of this said admin account and the same happens after saving the changes and refreshing the page it goes back to being the admin

I am the primary admin of the website

I am looking for a way to delete it through the PHPMyAdmin of my Cpanel or any other possible solution

Note: The email for this admin account also isn't the primary email for my WordPress site.

Comment: This isn't so much a programming problem as a Wordpress management question. I think you'll get better answers over at [Wordpress Development](wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I am looking for a way to delete it through the PHPMyAdmin of my Cpanel or any other possible solution

Answer (score -1):

You can delete that users record from wp_users table from direct Cpanel (Phpmyadmin)

Comment: From the question: _"**I have tried deleting through the following methods:** 1. Main users page in the dashboard 2. **wp_users page in Cpanel (Phpmyadmin)** 3. Tried to delete all fake users in metadata in Cpanel (Phpmyadmin)"_